# elastic search repo creation

Tags: nfs, elasticsearch, nfs4

I have configured elasticsearch with cluster and I have on nfs shared folder that mounted but when I try to create and repo path with this location I have faced some issues with permission

```
error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "repository_verification_exception",
            "reason": "[es_backup] [[SiVtYos-Qo-LRlL9UItz8A, 'RemoteTransportException[[tmz-mc2][192.0.0.21:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[es_backup] store location [/opt/nfsstorage] is not accessible on the node [{tmz-mc2}{SiVtYos-Qo-LRlL9UItz8A}{Q4BYe8zVT5-73PNYRoWuIQ}{192.0.0.21}{192.0.0.21:9300}]]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/opt/nfsstorage/tests-M9t7KzhsTOmzR5tUVh7utQ/data-SiVtYos-Qo-LRlL9UItz8A.dat];']]"
         }
```

Comment: You don't have access to the share. What more do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account under which this ES-node is running has access to the share. This is default set to the Local System account, but in case of shares, you'll need to modify this to an AD-account.